# Why I cannot use instance member within property initializer in struct but Apple can?

Tags: swift

I am trying to feed my property of a custom struct with a function but Xcode complain that:
***cannot use instance member within property initializer***
So if is that so? why I can use UUID() for feeding my id in struct? after all UUID() is a function or computed property! How can I solve this issue?

```
    struct CustomStruct1 {
    
    let id: UUID = UUID()                   // << Here
    var component: String
    
}



struct CustomStruct2 {

    private static var indexOfId: Int = -1
    let customID: Int = idMacker()          // << Here
    var component: String

    private func idMacker() -> Int {
        
        CustomStruct2.indexOfId += 1
        return CustomStruct2.indexOfId
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that you can't call functions. It's that you can't use `self`.

```
let customID: Int = idMacker()
```

is actually:

```
let customID: Int = self.idMacker()
```

It's just that you omitted `self`.

You can't use `self` in property initialisers, because when variable initialisers are run, `self` is not fully initialised. `idMacker` could access some uninitialised properties of `self`, or it could make wrong assumptions that `self` is fully initialised.

Calling `UUID()` doesn't use `self`, so it's OK.

You can also call static methods, global functions, and so on, in a property initialiser, as long as you don't use `self`, implicitly or explicitly.

e.g. This is fine:

```
struct CustomStruct2 {

    private static var indexOfId: Int = -1
    let customID: Int = CustomStruct2.idMacker()
    var component: String

    private static func idMacker() -> Int {
        
        CustomStruct2.indexOfId += 1
        return CustomStruct2.indexOfId
    }
    
}
```

Comment: So with that all said, I think I must bring idMacker() out of Struct to make it usable like: let customID: Int = idMacker() , Is it right?

Comment: @willy You don't need to do that. You can make it static, see the code in my answer.

Comment: @willy You should post your own solution as an answer, rather than edit it into the question.

Answer (score 0):

As another way to answer this issue, may be this answer useful:

```
    struct CustomStruct3 {
    
    static var indexOfId: Int = -1
    let customID: Int = idMacker()
    var component: String
  
}


private func idMacker() -> Int {
    
    CustomStruct3.indexOfId += 1
    return CustomStruct3.indexOfId
    
}
```